# Why does default mount point of removable media contains username?

Tags: mount, manjaro, automounting, removable-storage

I'm using Manjaro Linux.
When I plug new removable devices like USB,
it is auto mounted on
`/run/media/<username>/<label>`.

Why does this path contains username?

I mean, it is plugged to machine itself, not to a specific user.
To me, just `media/<label>` or something would make more sense.
If multiple users are logged into same system, which username is used for this mount point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having per-user directories under `media` allows the system to set things up so that users can’t list others’ mounted media. The username chosen for a mount point when a device is inserted is that of the user currently using the console (I’m ignoring multi-seat setups here); the idea is that the user currently at the console is the one most likely to have connected the removable device.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the console"?

Comment: Using the screen, keyboard and mouse attached to the computer (as opposed to a remote session, or a physical session in the background).